# How to find Perron root

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following functions:
$$x_1 = \lambda \sum_j^3 a_{1j}\ x_j^\beta$$
$$x_2 = \lambda \sum_j^3 a_{2j}\ x_j^\beta$$
$$x_3 = \lambda \sum_j^3 a_{3j}\ x_j^\beta$$

where $x_i$ is unknown number, $a_{ij}$ is given number and the exponent $\beta$ is given . I write them as matrix form:

$$X = \lambda A Y$$

where $X = [x_1,x_2,x_3]^T$ , $Y = [x_1^\beta,x_2^\beta,x_3^\beta]^T$ and $A = \left[
 \begin{matrix}
   a_{11} \ \  a_{12}  \ \  a_{13}\\
   a_{21} \ \  a_{22}  \ \  a_{23}\\
   a_{31} \ \  a_{32}  \ \  a_{33}\\
  \end{matrix}
  \right]$

How to solve the maximal $\lambda $ and that the corresponding $X$?

---

---

The following question I asked before

How to solve the following function:
$$ \left[
 \begin{matrix}
   x_1  \\
   x_2 \\
   x_3 
  \end{matrix}
  \right] =\lambda \left[
 \begin{matrix}
   a_{11} \ \  a_{12}  \ \  a_{13}\\
   a_{21} \ \  a_{22}  \ \  a_{23}\\
   a_{31} \ \  a_{32}  \ \  a_{33}\\
  \end{matrix}
  \right]\left[
 \begin{matrix}
   x_1^\beta  \\
   x_2^\beta \\
   x_3^\beta 
  \end{matrix}
  \right]$$

In order to applying Perron-Frobenius theorem to this function and find Perron root and that the corresponding eigenvector, any operation should I need? Thank you!

Comment: The word "function" doesn't mean what you think it means. Also, there are 14 symbols in the equation – which one are you trying to solve for?

Comment: given $a_{ij} $ and solve $x_{i}$ and $\lambda$

Comment: And what does $\beta$ do?

Comment: @GerryMyerson  $x_i$ raised to the power $\beta&

Comment: @GerryMyerson I edit the question again,plz give me a hand,thank you

Comment: Is $\beta$ given, or unknown?

Comment: @GerryMyerson $\beta$ is given